# SQLite collapse using group by and ignore null

Tags: sqlite, group-by, grouping, coalesce

I got `users` table

```
id |name |email
-------------------------
1  |sam  |null
-------------------------
2  |sammy|qqq@example.com 
-------------------------
3  |samy |sam@example.com 
-------------------------
4  |sammy|null 
-------------------------
```

I want to merge all of the rows but keep the first row and replace all the null values from other rows.

So 2 valid results for me would be:

- `1  |sam  |qqq@example.com`
- `1  |sam  |sam@example.com`

I been trying to do something like that

```
select 1,id,name,coalesce(email) from users group by 1
```

But `coalesce` is not allowed to be used in this way.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation functions ignore NULL values, so you can use MIN() or MAX():

```
SELECT 1,
       id,
       name,
       COALESCE(email, (SELECT min(email) FROM users))
FROM users
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: it will fix the null but it can mess the first row. max on name can bring the wrong one

Comment: Your question says that any of the names is OK.

Comment: ok so I am not the best with words. But the two results that I show it's the only two that are valid. Changing the name is not an option. I want the first row to be as it is and replace all the null values in it with ANY of other values available. But if it's not null I want to keep it.